# Why can't I directly save the image returned by the network request to a file？

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I use `okhttp` to download a png picture,and I directly write it into a file named ****.png without decoder it to a bitmap firstly.But I can't open that file  and I can't display the picture saved by me.
So what't wrong here?Is there something else in the body of response?

```
response=client.newCall(request).execute();
in=response.body().byteStream();
out=new FileOutputStream(file);
byte[] bytes=new byte[1024];
while (in.read(bytes)!=-1){
    out.write(bytes);
}
```

the wrong message: png error bad adaptive filter value

However, if I decoder it into a bitmap and then compress it to the file,it works.The picture can be opened.

```
response=client.newCall(request).execute();
out=new FileOutputStream(file);
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,out);
```

Comment: And I really don't want to decode it to a bitmap first for it may cause OOM. This problem has bothered me this whole moring.Why it can't be written to file directly...

Comment: Why don't you simply use glide? It won't cause OOM.

Comment: you are right,I've replaced him with glide

,but I still want to konw what's wrong here...